# Проблема включения Apache в утилите MAMP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, apache, mamp

Во время нажатия кнопки Start Server загорается зеленый круг на Apache,через 1 секунду уже на MySQL,затем с Apache пропадает зеленый круг и остается только включенный MySQL

В настройке я ставил Apache по умолчанию ( В приоритете на включение )

Вот ролик с тем как это выглядит 
https://youtu.be/Aqgy64xS21g

Comment: зайди в tools настройки поищи поменяй порт поставь 8081

Comment: @Bloom в Tools нет ничего связанного с портами,есть Preferences где можно поменять порты Apache и MySQL > Я менял по очереди все на 8081 //Не помогло//

Comment: зачем все apache 8081  ssl 443, sql 3306

Comment: @Bloom Не сработало

Comment: установи xampp .